# Connect code throws exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, mysql

I can't connect to MySQL server. Throws exception

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it  `mysql address ip`

I don't know how to do, i don't have mysql server for own use, i'm using sql hosting so i can't write commands.

My C# code:

```
Database.SQLConnection sql = new Database.SQLConnection();
if(sql.IsConnect())
 {
 MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE username='" + metroTextBox1.Text + "' AND password='" + metroTextBox2.Text + "' ;", sql.GetConnection());
 MySqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Database API by `Ocph23`

```
namespace Database
{
    public class SQLConnection
    {
        public SQLConnection() { }
        private string databaseName = string.Empty;
        public string DatabaseName
        {
            get { return databaseName; }
            set { databaseName = value; }
        }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        private MySqlConnection Connection = null;
        private static SQLConnection _instance = null;
        public static SQLConnection Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)

            _instance = new SQLConnection();
            return _instance;
        }

        public bool IsConnect()
        {
            bool result = true;
            if (Connection == null)
            {
                if (databaseName == string.Empty)
                    result = false;
                string StrCon = string.Format("Server=x; port=3306; database=x; UID=x; password=x", databaseName);
                Connection = new MySqlConnection(StrCon);
                Connection.Open();
                result = true;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return Connection;
        }



        public void Close()
        {
            Connection.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

What is wrong? Maybe error is on sql server side? firewall or something?

Comment: Have you checked the port no. or simply use define connection string in web.config files and call here .

Comment: Is there a policy in place which blocks the port being used, or blocks the IP address of the calling application? It could be it needs to be added to a whitelist.